# Sitefinity 5.3: How do I order my CSS?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, sitefinity

What I'm trying to do is include my own style.css file in the template that I'm building. In Visual Studio, I've opened `~/Template/App_Themes/Global/cssLoadOrder.xml` and ordered the CSS files how I'd like them to appear in the page. However, when I upload the template to Sitefinity, none of the CSS files from `cssLoadOrder.xml` appear anywhere in the HTML that is generated.

In 5.2, the CSS files from `cssLoadOrder.xml` were appended to the end of the `<head>`.

In 5.3, the only thing being appended to the end of the `<head>` is `<link href="/Default2/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?...">`, ignoring the CSS files from `cssLoadOrder.xml`.

How can I link to my own CSS as well as remove the default `Reset.css` file from being loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality or process hasn't changed between v5.2 - v5.3 so the normal workflow of adding a new theme will still work.

1. Create a new theme with the following folder structure from the root of your application:

   \App_Data\Sitefinity\WebsiteTemplates\MyTheme\App_Themes\MyTheme1
2. In the MyTheme1 folder, add 3 folders (global, styles and Images).
3. add a file called cssLoadOrder.xml with the following sample [cssLoadOrder.xml](https://github.com/jbokkers/SF-BOILERPLATED/blob/master/Boilerplate/App_Themes/Boilerplate/Global/cssLoadOrder.xml)
   Where sfnormalize.min.css and sfproject.min.css are the name of your css file(s).
4. Login to Sitefinity's backend and go to

   Administration>>Settings>>Advanced>>Appearance>>Frontend themes
5. Select create new and fill in the fields:
   Name: MyTheme1
   Path: ~/App_Data/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/MyTheme1/App_Themes/MyTheme1
6. Logout (and recycle to avoid caching issues).
7. Login to Sitefinity's backend and go to 
   Design>>Page Template
8. Choose the Template your page is using and click on it to edit.
9. On the top right part of the screen click on the Theme button and select 'MyTheme1' from the dropdown.

For a screenshot of the rendered source, [click here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19007909/sitefinity/sfv533900-custom_theme.png).

---

Those steps can be cumbersome, so as an alternative, you could use the free Sitefinity Thunder extension ([download link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/381fde64-9898-4a5d-ae20-861e119bbf92))

Once installed and setup, just open your solution in VisualStudio and select Project >> Add new item. There you'll find several Sitefinity types, including a Sitefinity Theme.

This will automatically take care of steps 1 to 6 and all you're left to do is apply that new theme to whatever template you like (step 7-9).

---

If you'd like to read more about it, the [official documentation](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/designer-s-guide/themes/applying-a-theme) has extensive coverage on how to apply themes/

Comment: Perfect! I was using Thunder, but the step I missed was step 9. The theme was still set to Basic. Thanks!